# Is it possible to define a scoped callback function in a C struct?

Tags: c++, c, struct

The C struct `AvCodecContext` in libav (ffmpeg) has a callback function called `get_format`. I have a class where each instance has its own `AvCodecContext` instance, so each one will have an specific callback.

Is it possible to create different callbacks for each instance?

Here's what the callback should look like:

```
    enum AVPixelFormat get_hw_format(AVCodecContext *ctx, const enum AVPixelFormat *pix_fmts)
    {
        const enum AVPixelFormat *p;

        for (p = pix_fmts; *p != -1; p++) {
            if (*p == hw_pix_fmt)
                return *p;
        }

        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to get HW surface format.\n");
        return AV_PIX_FMT_NONE;
    }
```

each callback should have a different `AVPixelFormat hw_pix_fmt`.

If the project was C++ only, I could use lambda functions, but it's not.

Is there a way?

Comment: I'm not familiar with libav, but it looks like the `AVCodecContext` struct has a `void*` field named `opaque` that you can stuff whatever data you want into, probably for exactly this reason.

Comment: @MilesBudnek this is a good idea, thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by "C struct has a callback function"? Member functions are a C++ thing.

Comment: @eerorika I meant that this struct holds a pointer to a function

Comment: @GuerlandoOCs oh. In that case I don't see a problem. Yes, every function pointer can point to a different function.